# Trying to connect vnc server from my Pi 3 but getting blank screen in vnc viewer

Tags: pi-3, vnc

Hey I have setup the VNC server and running chrome there and want to see the same view here in my RaspberryPi3. But I am getting the blank screen.

I have done the same setup in my laptop it is working fine and I am able to see the view using chrome vnc viewer. Since I cant run chrome vnc viewer in RaspberryPi because it doesnt support Native NACI client.So I am using default vnc-viewer in RaspberryPi. But getting the blank screen.

Raspberry pi model

cat /proc/device-tree/model --- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3